# npm install not pulling in devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I have npm v 1.2.32

When I run:
$npm install mongo-migrate

it does not install mongodb which is a devDependency.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install won't install devDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you install a package from the NPM repository, dev dependencies won't automatically be installed as well (because those dependencies shouldn't be necessary to get the main package working properly).

You need to explicitly instruct npm to install dev dependencies too:

```
npm install mongo-migrate --dev
```

**Update**

The `--dev` command has been deprecated.

> **npm** WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead.

```
npm install mongo-migrate --only=dev
```

Comment: this is a bad answer. This command install devDepend recursively so that it's not usable most of the time

Comment: @Jake the answer is more than 2 years old. Feel free to create your own answer.

Answer (score 85):

Although not directly related to this question, it may be of interest to some to know that if environment variable `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`, npm will ignore `devDependencies` when executing `npm install`.

Comment: This saved me another couple hours of comparing the differences in two dev environments. I had line-by-line compared the `npm config ls -l` right before I found this answer. Thanks!

Comment: The npm docs do actually include this note (https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/95e59b287c9517780318e145371a859e8ebb2d20), but their docs online are not up to date with that info yet.

Comment: upvote, is there a way to force npm install to install devDependencies in production  ? Or should I just add the builded directory to my git repository ?

Comment: I work on windows and had to set my NODE_ENV to production globally. This answer really helped me.

Comment: What value should I set for `NODE_ENV` to get it install devDependencies?

Answer (score 2):

`npm i <package>   # without devDependencies
cd node_modules/<package>
npm i             # include devDependencies`

"npm i  --dev" is not correct, since it install devDependencies recursively.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue only it was due to the fact that I had devDependencies defined twice in my package.json.

I had written it in manually misspelled and during troubleshooting ran some --save-dev installs which made it show up twice. Incidentally if you include the "devDependencies" twice in your package.json, npm will not install them.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally had to install devDependencies even with NODE_ENV=production.

I usually use this workaround.

```
// temporarily change NODE_ENV to other value...
NODE_ENV=development npm install
```