# NPM: To install a package along with its own devDeps

Tags: npm

I am just getting myself familiar with command line tools like npm. I've been searching around for the answer but was not able to find a clear one.

What I am trying to do is to install materialize-css package into my test package, as well as its devDependencies, like "autoprefixer". [This is materializeCSS's package.json file](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/package.json).

Here's what I do:
Under my newly created and blank folder "testProject", I use `npm init` to create a `package.json` file for my test package:

```
{
  "name": "create_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Setting up a project",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "shenk wen",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Then, I do

```
npm install materialize-css
```

I was expecting the above command would install all the dependencies and devDependencies of `materialize-css`, but only the dependencies is being installed. I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374278/npm-install-not-pulling-in-devdependencies) and the accepted answer suggests adding `--dev` to the command. But that seems not the answer I am looking for because `--dev` would only make `materialize-css` a devDependency of my test package, but not installing its own devDependencies. The other answers are not so straightforward. Is there any parameter I can use to achieve this? Or do I have to change the env_variable which I don't know how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older npm versions, 'npm install --dev' installed all devDependencies of all your dependencies. This also used to work in a recursive fashion, so you end up downloading also devDependencies of devDependencies of your dependencies and so on. This resulted in enormously long install time / download size.

Also, the purpose of the feature is questionable: Why should you care about devDeps of your deps? For these reasons --dev was removed from npm:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5554

Current behavior for 'npm install' is: install all deps and devDeps for the 'main' package (the one you 'npm install'-ed in the first place), but when recursing, install only deps (and no devDeps).

If you want to install & save the dependency to your package.json, you should use --save or --save-dev, I don't think --dev does this.

Comment: `npm i materialize-css --save-dev` will not install materialize-css package's devDependencies. Insteadly it will only install materialize-css as a devDependency to my test project.

Comment: yeah, exactly. There is no point in installing devDependencies of materialize-css; you're not developing materialize-css, you're just using it as it comes in your project. For just using the project installing not-dev-dependencies is enough - which is exactly what npm install does.

Comment: I am aware that but I was asking whether there is a straightforward way to install devDependencies. What if I wanna fork materialize-css?

Comment: If you run 'npm install' on your materialize-css fork, you WILL get all the deps + devDeps (try it!). This is because npm distinguish, whether materialize-css is installed as the top-level (main) package or whether it is just some dependency of something another (such as, your test project). If it is the main package, you'll get the deps + devDeps. If it is just the dependency, you'll get just deps and no devDeps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `devDependencies` of a module you've installed as a dependency to your project, you almost certainly want to `git clone` that module's repo or fork it instead. When you run `npm install` in your cloned repo, that will also install all of the module's `devDependencies`.

(I'm not a developer by trade and my npm-fu was a bit rusty, so I confused myself about what I was trying to do. Tomas Kulich's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34509980/4200446) *"Why should you care about devDeps of your deps?"* helped me realize the error of my ways.)