# npm install won't install devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

On windows for some reason when I run `npm install` it won't install **devDependencies**. AFAIK it should. If I run `npm install --dev` **devDependencies** are installed. I don't understand why `npm install` doesn't install **devDependencies** too, but installs only dependencies. What could be the reason? How can I fix it?

Maybe something is wrong with my *package.json*? It is listed below if it may be helpful:

```json
{
  "name": "try-brunch",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "brunch": "^2.0.4",
    "cssnano-brunch": "^1.1.5",
    "javascript-brunch": "^1.8.0",
    "sass-brunch": "^1.9.2",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "^1.7.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Say you write an app, and you need a logger or webpack plugin. those are devdeps. those need to be installed. npm doesn't install those in some cases.

Comment: I mean, the installation for `devDependencies` is needed only when you **write** the package (application). Using it does not require the `devDependencies`. So **it is reasonable for `devDependencies` to require extra flags to be installed.** If `npm install` installed `devDependencies` **by default**, the _users_ would get redundant packages as well.

Comment: the documented behaviour is that when I do `npm i` in my folder it grabs py `package.json` and installs both deps and devdeps. This is the way it's intended to work and it makes sense (e.g. when I do `npm i` after `git clone` I expect to have all I need, including e.g. webpack plugins). This question addresses a bug, when the actual behaviour is different from intended. pls, take a look at docs - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install . There's a flag to not install devdeps, but the default behavior is to install them, which makes perfect sense and is what everybody expects

Comment: I don't see any sane reasons to make me remember to run another command to install e.g. webpack plugins or typescript type defs or any other devdeps every time I pull. `npm i`  should bootstrap both, which is the intended, sane and documented behavior, so I honestly don't understand why you say that this issue should be a standard

Comment: regarding your point that `Using it does not require the devDependencies` - I'm a bit confused. When I run `npm i` on CI or server my app needs e.g. typescript, jest, webpack, whatever devdeps to get built, so I don't get which `using` was this about

Comment: `when I do npm i in my folder it grabs my package.json and installs both deps and devdeps.` -- Okay, it seems we're arguing on different things: (what I'm saying is) installing already-published packages with `npm install <package name>`, and (what you're saying is) `npm install`ing with your local `package.json`.

Comment: The context in which I said `using` is this: [“If someone is planning on downloading and **using your module in their program**, then they probably don't want or need to download and build the external test or documentation framework that you use. **In this case,** it's best to map these additional **items in a `devDependencies` object.**”](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies).

Comment: I'm sorry for misreading the question and offending you. This is my fault mistaking your context.

Comment: no worries. yes, it was about installing kinda my devdeps, not devdeps of libs. There might be issues with those as well, but I haven't yet ran into such

Comment: @КонстантинВан Because it need to be installed under Jenkins by scripts.

Answer (score 425, accepted):

Check the NPM docs for [install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

> With the `--production` flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies."
>
> The `--only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]}` argument will cause either only devDependencies or only non-devDependencies to be installed regardless of the NODE_ENV."

Have you tried

```
npm install --only=dev
```

If you are worried that your **package.json** might be incorrect, best thing to do is this. Create a new folder, and run:

```
npm init --yes
```

Then:

```
npm install --save-dev brunch@^2.0.4
npm install --save-dev cssnano-brunch@^1.1.5
npm install --save-dev javascript-brunch@^1.8.0
npm install --save-dev sass-brunch@^1.9.2
npm install --save-dev uglify-js-brunch@^1.7.8
npm install jquery@^2.1.4 --save
```

And you should be good to go! Otherwise, will keep posting other options.

Check your npm configuration:

```
npm config list
```

npm gets its config settings from the command line, environment variables, and npmrc files. So check environment variables, and the [npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) file.

**Still failing?**

Ok, create a new folder, ideally somewhere else on your filesystem. ie. not in same folder hierarchy. For instance, C:\myNewFolder - the closer to the base C: drive the better.

Then run:

```
npm init --yes
```

Now run:

```
npm install underscore --save
```

and finally:

```
npm install mocha --save-dev
```

Does everything work as expected?

What I am trying to do is understand whether your problem is global, or something local to the previous folder and dependencies.

Comment: npm install --only=dev  installs devdeps, but I would like to install both deps and devdeps at once. package.json seems to be ok, as recreating it doesn't change anything. Am I right that NODE_ENV exists both globally, as a default value and locally, as a value for project? Where can I check and change these values on windows (I've looked and I have no system variable NODE_ENV)

Comment: @TristanTzara - i work almost exclusively on MAC these days. However, from memories of days gone by (years ago on NT and XP) - can you type something like "set" into command prompt window..  Else go to something like System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables and check your entries there.  You are looking for a "key" with NODE_ENV. I will google now for a windows option but posted this in case it helps.

Comment: Link here - http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-see-names-and-values-of-environment-variables-in-windows-8-and-windows-7/

Comment: @TristanTzara - that is good to know. One thought, check all the parent directories above your directory that doesn't work. Look for an existing node_modules folder... npm will search upwards when trying to resolve a dependency and it might be something weird like it is picking up an existing installed module further up the directory tree, and therefore refusing to install yours in the child folder. The usual place is right under your home directory.. Good luck and thanks for acknowledging my answer :D

Comment: Or just copy your failing package.json file to a folder you know works, and see if you get different results (working) at that new location.

Comment: `npm install && npm install --only=dev` Thanks!

Comment: Also `only` option is deprecated, you could use either `omit` or `include` which better suits you.

Comment: `@devDependencies` !== `devDependencies`. FML

Comment: `--also=dev` appears deprecated and prints a warning. see my answer.

Answer (score 110):

Check if npm config production value is set to true. If this value is true, it will skip over the dev dependencies.

Run `npm config get production`

To set it: `npm config set -g production false`

Comment: I wonder if, somewhere between npm 5.x and npm 6.x, if no value was set, the default become `true` rather than `false`?

Answer (score 60):

make sure you don't have env variable `NODE_ENV` set to 'production'.

If you do, dev dependencies will not be installed without the `--dev` flag

Comment: I've taken a look at my system variables and I even don't have this one there. Maybe I look at the wrong place?

Comment: Please note that `npm install --dev` installs devDependencies _recursively_.  This is almost never what you want, and is in fact [deprecated](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6200).

Comment: Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead

Comment: If I have `NODE_ENV` set to `'production'`, how can I install both dependencies and devDependencies, but not optionalDependencies?

Comment: `npm install --include dev` does the trick @MaxCoplan

Comment: npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--also=dev` instead.

Comment: thanks @AmirSavand you gave me the answer I needed :)

Comment: `--include=dev` might be a useful flag to someone out there.

Comment: @AmirSavand `--also=dev` did the trick for me too.

Comment: `--also=dev` appears deprecated and prints a warning. see my answer.

Answer (score 29):

You can use the short way for installation dependencies only for development as follows:

```
npm i -D <dependencies-names>
```

Comment: that's not at all what the OP asked

Answer (score 23):

I had a `package-lock.json` file from an old version of my package.json, I deleted that and then everything installed correctly.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem.  `npm install --only=dev` didn't work, and neither did `npm rebuild`.  Ultimately, I had to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again.  That fixed it for me.

Comment: Same. I was copy another project and to make some modifications, this is what I have to do.

Answer (score 11):

As of now you could use:

```
npm i --also=dev
```

Comment: npm WARN config also Please use --include=dev instead.

Comment: `--also=dev` appears deprecated and prints a warning. see my answer.

Comment: Neither of them are actually installing the dev dependencies here, with `npm@10.5.0`, and into a clean `npm init -y`.  It's possible I've messed something up though.

Answer (score 10):

I have the same issue because I set the `NODE_ENV=production` while building Docker. Then I add one more `npm install --only=dev`. Everything works fine. I need the devDependencies for building TypeSciprt modules

```
RUN npm install
RUN npm install --only=dev
```

Comment: `--include=dev` is a little easier. see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your `package.json` is valid...

I had the following error...

`npm WARN Invalid name: "blah blah blah"`

and that, similarly, caused `devDependencies` not to be installed.

FYI, changing the `package.json` "name" to `blah-blah-blah` fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

So the way I got around this was in the command where i would normally run `npm install` or `npm ci`, i added `NODE_ENV=build`, and then `NODE_ENV=production` after the command, so my entire command came out to:

```
RUN NODE_ENV=build && npm ci && NODE_ENV=production
```

So far I haven't had any bad reactions, and my development dependencies which are used for building the application all worked / loaded correctly.

I find this to be a better solution than adding an additional command like `npm install --only=dev` because it takes less time, and enables me to use the `npm ci` command, which is faster and specifically designed to be run inside CI tools / build scripts. (See [npm-ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html) documentation for more information on it)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was that I had the `NODE_ENV` variable set to production in the same terminal session I ran `npm install`.

For my build to run properly I was not allowed to change the value of `NODE_ENV` so I forced npm to install all the dependencies by adding the `--production=false` flag to it: `npm install --production=false` as [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install).

If you don't need `NODE_ENV` to be set to `production` you can simply type `export NODE_ENV=development` to your terminal to overwrite its value and run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 3):

The correct working answer - as of 2024 - to install all project NPM dependencies, is as follows:

```bash
npm install --include=dev
```

The above works even when `NODE_ENV=production` is set.

It correctly installs all project `dependencies` and `devDependencies` together.

#### `--also` appears to be deprecated

I tried using `--also` instead of `--include` as mentioned in comments, but that option seems deprecated in newer node / NPM versions. I see a warning printed in the console, as shown below.

```
$ npm i --also=dev
npm WARN config also Please use --include=dev instead.
```

> Tested in node `v20.9.0` and npm `10.4.0`

### TL;DR

Pass in `--include=dev` to `npm i`, for both **dev** and **production** environments.

Answer (score 2):

Got a similar error after running `npm-check-updates -u`. Solved it by removing `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`. After that a new `npm install` and everything worked.

My exception:

> Failed to load parser '@typescript-eslint/parser' declared in
> 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app#overrides[0]': Cannot find
> module '@typescript-eslint/parser'

Answer (score 0):

As @Ale told, we can use `npm i -D <some_module_name>` or `npm i --save-dev <some_module_name>` **now**.
It seems command was changed at some point of node version.
Offical ([npm dependencies and devDependencies](https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-dependencies-and-devdependencies)) says following.

> When you add the -D flag, or --save-dev, you are installing it as a development dependency, which adds it to the devDependencies list.