# Should "NODE_ENV=development npm install" in package.json "scripts" install devDependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to call `npm install` **from an npm script**, but the devDependencies won't install even if I set the `NODE_ENV` to `development` like that:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "NODE_ENV=development npm i"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

This way, only the dependencies are installed when running `npm run deploy`, not the devDependencies.
Is this by design?

To give a bit more information, the `NODE_ENV` on the machine is set to `production` and should stay that way. I want to set the environment variable just for one script line and that normally works for other scripts. The line sets the `NODE_ENV` correctly and the installer runs, but it's not taking the environment variable into account - calling `npm install` from a script seems to run always as if the `--production` flag is set.

So, running the line `NODE_ENV=development npm i` from the shell installs devDependencies and dependencies (it overwrites the NODE_ENV variable which is set on the machine, just for this one command), but running the same line in an package.json scripts block ignores the NODE_ENV overwriting.

- The `--production` flag doesn't help, because I also want to install the devDependencies.
- The `--only[prod|dev]` also doesn't do what I want, because it only installs either only dev **or** only prod dependencies if I read that right.

The following line in the `package.json` correctly prints `development` as the environment variable, even if `production` is set on the machine:

```
"scripts": {
  "envTest": "NODE_ENV=development node -e 'console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);'"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install won't install devDependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies)

Comment: I think you have it backwards npm install will install all dependencies.

Comment: I edited my answer and tried to give more context, it's not about installing from the shell like in the linked question.