# npm install showing up to date instead of installing the packages

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install

I am having some trouble with npm install.

`npm install package-name` is working perfectly, but when I add a new dependency in the `package.json` file manually (by pulling via git) and then try to `npm install` only, it returns

```
up to date in 4.2 sec
```

And doesn't install the package.

FYI: I am using `git` to pull the `package.json` file. So there is no any issue in the package name. It just doesn't work when i pull and try to install it with `npm install` only.

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "ap",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^4.1.0",
    "angular2-busy": "^2.0.4",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-toaster": "^4.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.15",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-simple-timer": "^1.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, none of these answers solved for me

Answer (score 4):

As @j7an said, the problem must depend on the environment. I had the same problem and I didn't know how my NODE_ENV was set to production. Anyway, I did this: (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies) )

1. Remove `package-lock.json`
2. Remove `node_modules`

After that:

```
npm install
npm install --only=dev
```

This must solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue when I ran `export NODE_ENV=production` based on the book "Modern JavaScript". After deleting node_modules, package.json, and also clearing npm cache didn't fix the issue, I found the answer from this stackoverflow entry: [npm install won't install devDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies)

To fix the issue, I ran `export NODE_ENV=` which removed the production flag. Once I did that I was able to install dev dependencies again. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will check and let you know.