# Reference Includes source that is not in the repository

Tags: autorest

I have cloned the code [for autorest.csharp](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.csharp) and it's submodules
However test project has a missing dependency

The build error is

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Modeler' 
does not exist in the namespace 'AutoRest' 
(are you missing an assembly reference?)    autorest.csharp.test
```

However the solution file contains the following

```
  <ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="autorest.modeler">
      <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)\node_modules\@microsoft.azure\autorest.modeler\src\bin\netcoreapp2.0\autorest.modeler.dll</HintPath>
      <!-- <HintPath>C:\work\oneautorest\autorest.modeler\src\bin\netcoreapp2.0\autorest.modeler.dll</HintPath> -->
    </Reference>
    <ProjectReference Include="$(SolutionDir)src/autorest.csharp.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

How do include the code ( or if necessary the .dll) for the missing dependency?

I can see the source for the modeler is at 
[this repository](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.modeler) but how should I be accessing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@microsoft.azure/autorest.modeler` is  declared in the [`package.json devDependencies` section](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.csharp/blob/bda72d955b75486b20769636bf1e5c4bc84f02f8/package.json#L36).

[That devDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies) section is described as:

> If someone is planning on downloading and using your module in their program, then they probably don't want or need to download and build the external test or documentation framework that you use.
>
> In this case, it's best to map these additional items in a devDependencies object.
>
> These things will be installed when doing `npm link` or `npm install` from the root of a package, and can be managed like any other npm configuration param.

So in your case, try:

```
NODE_ENV=development npm install
```

For Windows:

```
cmd /v /c "set NODE_ENV=development&& npm install"
```

(not the *lack* of space between `development` and `&&`: that is important)

In order to get and install development dependencies as well as the main production project.

Or, as documented in "[`npm install` won't install devDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34719468/6309)":

```
npm install --only=dev
```

Also Check if npm config production value is set to true. If this value is true, it will skip over the dev dependencies.

Also: Run `npm config get production`, make sure it is set to `false`:

```
npm config set -g production false
```

If `npm install --only=dev`/`npm rebuild` don't work, you might need to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again

Comment: I have npm installed byt I get NODE_ENV is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Yes, On Windows, the synax would be different. Does `npm install --only=dev` at least allow you to get those dev dependencies?

Comment: Yes, running it now

Comment: @KirstenGreed I have edited the answer to add the Windows syntax for `NODE_ENV`.

Comment: I get the following error post this `Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported autorest.csharp.test`. Any takers?

Comment: @RajKumar Maybe try and restore NuGet packages, as in https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/1593#issuecomment-360215034

Comment: So the problem was Resharper doing something that wasn't expected. I disabled resharper and things seemed to kick in