# Install published npm-package dev dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have published a npm package to npm.

When I tried to install it anywhere through `npm i <package-name>`, It's installing all dependencies in it. How to install dev-dependencies of it, without navigating it to that directory.

The below are properties from published npm-package.

```
{
    "name":"test-package",
    "dependencies": {
       "pg":"^7.7.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
       "gremlin":"^3.3.3"
    }
}
```

My requirement is, when I type `npm i test-package` in my project location, I found **pg** in my node_modules directory, but when I run in development environment, I need **gremlin** also to be installed. How can I install npm-package along with all of its dependencies(dev also).

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers/solutions to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies)? _(Note: some answers are outdated)_

Comment: I tried using
`npm i test-package --dev`
`npm i test-package --only=dev`

But I'm unable to install devDependencies of that (test-package).

Answer (score -1):

To install a package as a dev dependency you need to specify by using `npm install <package-name> --save-dev`.
[image: package.json]