# How to use package.json on a project that is not a module

Tags: npm, package.json

So we've been using npm and package.json to build front-end apps for a long time.

It's fairly common to see this:

- dependencies

  - lodash
  - react
- devDependencies

  - webpack
  - eslint

But if you build your project on the production environment, it [won't install the dev dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies).

Webpack is not really a "devDependencies" it is a "buildDependencies" it isn't really used by the project, but you need it to be able to build the project.

But eslint is a devDependency, you don't really need apart from "developing".

---

so a more correct way to do this would be:

- bundledDependencies

  - react
  - lodash
- dependencies

  - webpack
- devDependencies

  - eslint

but after reading the documentation bundledDependencies are [not really meant for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies/22004559#22004559).

Should I actually shrinkwrap my project, so I can be sure that when the CI builds the project is is actually downloading the same thing I tested in my local machine?

So my question is what is the correct way of setting up a package.json for a project that is not really a module?

Comment: in your case (not a module) what is the hazard of putting everything in `dependencies` ?

Comment: it just makes managing dependencies a bit harder

Comment: in what way does this impact their management? For a module that someone else is using in their project, in yours I don't see how it makes any difference. It seems like splitting them into different categories is what is making it harder to manage

Comment: @azium yes the only benefit seems to be separating, dependencies of the build pipeline, and dependencies used by the project itself.