# Does npm install -g (global) <package_name> install its devDependencies?

Tags: npm

The npm [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install) state that `npm install` by default installs both `dependencies` and `devDependencies` listed in your `package.json`. If you want to only install `dependencies` then use the `--production` flag.

When you install a package then the docs state

> NOTE: The --production flag has no particular meaning when adding a dependency to a project.

My question is regarding the package your installing's dependencies. Does its `devDependencies` get installed?

What about when you install a package globally using `npm install -g <package_name>`?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies) discusses `devDepedencies` when installing your own dependencies from `package.json`, but not about what occurs when installing a specific package.

Comment: The documentation looks confusing in that regard but it seems that it depends entirely on the production flag, and that the flag is ignored only when adding a new library to a project, not when adding a global one or fetching missing things.

Comment: This would mean that when installing a package globally it installs devDependencies. Would that make sense, why would I need a package's devDependencies to be installed?