# Does AWS inspector include package vulnerabilities that are in yarn.lock but not installed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm

When using AWS inspector for ECR images, the results mentioned vulnerabilities that don't seem to be installed on the image.

This [article](https://snyk.io/news/snyk-security-intelligence-integrates-into-the-new-enhanced-amazon-inspector/) from snyk discusses how AWS Inspector is using Snyk to help with it's detecting.

#### Question:

My question is does AWS inspector or Snyk include package vulnerabilities that are in yarn.lock but not installed?

Is this the convention for other package inspectors, to include vulnerabilities in packages that aren't installed but are listed as dependencies?

This doesn't make sense, why would it be a vulnerability if the package is not actually installed.

#### More Info:

The reason I don't think the package is installed is because when I run `npm list` ([docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ls)) the vulnerable package is not listed.

Also when I test locally I don't see a `node_models` folder with the suspected package. I do see it listed in a `yarn.lock` file.

(The suspected package is a `devDependency` of a `dependency` of a `dependency` of a package that is installed globally)

#### Side Notes:

When I run `npm audit` ([docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-audit)) I don't see any security issues listed. `npm audit` has it's own issues with listing vulnerabilities that may not be a real issue (see [here](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/) and [enter link description here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174)), but at least it's not listing packages that aren't even installed.

This question may be dependent on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71693754/does-npm-install-g-global-package-name-install-its-devdependencies) question, regarding `devDependencies` being installed when installing a package (globally).

Comment: Yes, in my experience it is picking up devDependencies listed in yarn.lock, even though they aren't actually installed in the docker image.

Comment: @MarkB Am I correct in understanding that it's not a vulnerability if it's not installed? And that AWS Inspector should not include those vulnerabilities in their report?

Comment: There is another case happening with me. Its picking vulnerability from yarn.lock files that belong to dependency (e.g. from a package inside node_modules) but that are not actually installed.

Is there a way to avoid this false positives?

Comment: @MarkB may be you can help: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77314442/why-did-aws-inspector-detect-an-openssl-vulnerability)

Answer (score 1):

We solved this problem by manually deleting all yarn.lock files from our docker images as the last step:

```
RUN yarn install --production --silent --pure-lockfile --cache-folder /usr/app/yarn-cache  \
    # get rid of all yarn.lock files as the AWS Inspector thinks they contain vulnerabilities
    && rm -rf ./yarn-cache \
    && find . -type f -name 'yarn.lock' -delete
```

obviously the bit about the `--cache-folder` may not be relevant to you, we just keep the cache around through our multistage builds to speed things up