# npm WARN config dev Please use --include=dev instead

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-redux

Please help. I keep getting this error whenever installing a package or setting up a project in React

```
npm WARN config dev Please use --include=dev instead.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install won't install devDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies)

Comment: what exact line are you running?

Comment: This happens when ever i run any command starting with npm

Comment: possible short answer: replace `--save --dev` with `--save-dev`

Comment: I suspect quant2016 is correct; are you trying to install using npm but using the yarn syntax? With npm we want to use `npm install foo --save-dev` whereas with yarn we'd use `yarn add --dev`.

Answer (score -2):

sudo npm install cypress --save-dev