# devDependecies not installed with npm ci --include=dev

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, svelte

I use [rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup) to compile a Svelte application.
As you can see, Rollup is defined as a devdependency.

When running this pipeline, the pipeline exists with the following error:
`sh: 1: rollup: not found`
Could it be that devDependencies are not installed correctly?

**package.json**

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^2.67.2",
    ....
}
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
image: node:latest

cache:
  key:
    files:
      - package-lock.json
  paths:
    - .npm/

setup_firebase:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - npm i -g firebase-tools
    - echo FIREBASE_API_KEY=$FIREBASE_PROJECT_API_KEY >> .env

npm_install:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - npm ci --include=dev --cache .npm --prefer-offline

compile_app:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build

deploy_app:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - firebase deploy --only hosting --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
  only:
    refs:
      - main
```

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700610/npm-install-wont-install-devdependencies (maybe the issue is `NODE_ENV`)

Comment: Apart from the `NODE_ENV`, `--include=dev` should install devDependencies anyway, isn't it?

Comment: I have not found that argument in the documentation, does that even exist?